# Tar command not found in adb shell

Tags: android, linux, windows, command-line, adb

I am new to android sorry if i sound like a nub but .
I want to copy a tar file inside the device through adb . After that i would like to extract it inside the device through tar command line tool. Is it possible ? If yes how do i install tar ?

`zsh: command not found: tar`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
adb push 'pathOnDesktop' 'pathOnDevice'
```

For copying files already on the device to a different location use

```
adb shell cp source destination
```

tar utility is bundled with adb

Do to see available commands and arguments with tar

```
adb shell tar --help
```

and then

```
tar –xvzf filename
```

to extract the zipped files.

Comment: Check tar options. Use `-z` if the original tar was compressed